# Is there is any benefit/privileges for increasing impact/people reached? Why is it counted?

Tags: discussion, people-reached

If I earn 20k rep I will be a trusted user, and for 25k rep I can get access to site analytics.

What about impact/people reached? If there's no benefit, why is it counted?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290491/what-does-people-reached-signify-and-how-is-it-calculated

Comment: I wouldn't say it is "counted". It is guesstimated.

Comment: @rene i think you are right..it's guesstimated..

Comment: "Low hanging fruit"... Easy to implement, makes people think "I'm so cool" and increases the chances of people contributing more.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's no benefit.  It's just for fun.

A lot of people post on Stack Exchange to help people with their questions and answers. Seeing a concrete of number of people "helped" by their content is a good way to quantify that and give people an acknowledgement of their contribution and motivation to contribute more.

Comment: Yes, what Ryan said.

Comment: @Yaakov new badge request: "Official Stamp", awarded for getting official confirmation from SE staff on one of your posts. :-)